# Displaylink not detecting monitor

Tags: drivers, 22.04, monitor, displaylink, docking

The machine I'm using runs Ubuntu 22.04. The screenshot below shows the details of the machine itself.

I want to connect it to the Dell 3100 docking station. I have installed and tested both DisplayLink drivers: the driver from the Dell site that has support for Ubuntu 22.04 (5.6.0-59.176, A01) and the driver from synaptics.com (Release: 5.6.1) for Ubuntu specifically.

When executing the .run file in the terminal console initially, I get a blinking cursor. I have to terminate the process because it never finishes the installation. When I conduct a second installation, it seems the installation goes through. However, it seems the driver does not install properly because my screen monitor does not come up.

Please see the screenshots below. Please advise on mitigating this issue and thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Solution for me was to uninstall the driver and install it via apt. (Don't install it manually as that does not work)

Step1: sudo displaylink-installer uninstall

Step2: Download Synaptics APT Repository Ubuntu LTS
https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

Step3: sudo apt install ./Downloads/synaptics-repository-keyring.deb

Step4: sudo apt update

Step5: sudo apt install displaylink-driver

You might need to restart your machine. Enjoy!

Comment: I usually go with [this repo](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian) to get it installed yet after an Ubuntu OS update it stopped working. This fix it for me! thanks @Faisal!

Comment: No problems. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

I have also got the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and feel installation was stuck
Had to kill all the displaylink installers

Please try this and see whether it helps

sudo apt-get install evdi-dkms

And after that displays are working for me

Reference: https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=68202

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, install evdi-dkms separately **before** running the displaylink*.run script. All this on a **fresh** installation (i.e. **before** attempting to install any DisplayLink package). To be on a safe side, do a sudo apt install dkms even before installing evdi-dkms.

The sequence is this:

1. Clean Ubuntu install;
2. Install dkms and reboot;
3. Install evdi-dkms; will ask to create a new password;
4. Reboot and follow the prompts: pick "install key" and folow the prompts; at some point it will ask you to type in the password picked out previously; reboot when finished;
5. Run the displaylink*.run package
6. Reboot;
7. Bob's your uncle.

Comment: At step 4, after reboot there are 3 options. But none of them says "install key". Confused and desperate, I just picked the first one that says something about "MOK". It did asked for the password I created in step 3. I truly regret that I didn't take a photo...